# Как запустить скрипт после полной загрузки страницы?

Tags: javascript, html, alert, prompt

Как показать `HELLO !` до вывода переменной `name в alert` ?

В коде, который размещен, в начале выходит скрипт, который спрашивает имя, выводит имя в `alert`, только потом выходит сообщение `HELLO!`, нужно чтобы было наоборот.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
  <h1> HELLO !</h1>
  <script>
    var name = prompt("Ваше имя?", "");
    alert(name);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `setTimeout(function(){...ваш код...},1000)`

Comment: вообще, в зависимости от браузера данный код и так будет работать так как ты хочешь

Comment: например FF отображает разметку до показа блокирующего окна.

Comment: Что значит FF разметка ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используй отдельно файл js и установи атрибут async

```
<script async src='script.js'></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Сомнительный, однако рабочий вариант:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <h1> HELLO !</h1>
    <script>
        let counter = 0;
        function main() {
            if (counter === 0) {
                counter++;
                requestAnimationFrame(main)
            }
            else if (counter === 1) {
                let name = prompt('Ваше имя?', '');
                alert(name);
            }
        }
        requestAnimationFrame(main);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
});
```

если в скрип записать такую строку, то скрипт отработает после того как загрузиться страница, так же ты можешь туда добавить setTimeout чтобы задержать появление алерта еще на какой то срок например вот так

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log( "ready!" );
    }, 4000);
});
```